# Using PolyLang to update keywords in shopping cart (AJAX/WooCommerce)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

With help from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941502/refresh-update-minicart-with-ajax-in-woocommerce/) I've got a function working that displays and updates the amount and total price of the shopping cart in WooCommerce with AJAX. The problem I didn't think off was that I use PolyLang on the site and therefore would like the keywords for "product" and "products" to translate when the user changes the language on the page.

I've tried to use the `pll_current_language()` hook in a conditional before the AJAX call in `functions.php` that then defines the variables `$item` and `$items` depending on what the current language is and inserts those keywords in the string that the AJAX returns. I've used a similar conditional in template files, so it's working there.

However, it's not working as expected with this function. This is how I have set it up:

**functions.php**

```
function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();

    // Cart Translations
    $lang = pll_current_language();
    $item;
    $items;

    if ($lang == 'sv'){
    $item = "produkt";
    $items = "produkter";
    } else if ($lang == 'en') {
        $item = "product";
    $items = "products";
    }

    ?>
    <a class="cart-customlocation wpmenucart" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d ' . $item, '%d ' . $items, WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    <?php
    $fragments['a.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment', 30, 1 );
```

The problem I'm getting is that the `pll_current_language()` hook always returns "sv", even if I visit the english page. So it seems like I can't use that hook in the functions.php, or am I missing something? Do you have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at the same solution. Then, 
I just realised the $lang = pll_current_language(); is not picking up the cookie correctly. So as workaround. I started using $_COOKIE for that.

```
function sn_get_cart_url() {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['pll_language'];
    $cart_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_page_id' );

    if(function_exists('pll_get_post')) {
       $cart_page_id = pll_get_post($cart_page_id, $lang); 
    }
    return get_permalink($cart_page_id);
}
```

I am not digging much deep in Plugins coding. But this might solve your issue.

Comment: Cool! So I should be able to use it like `$lang = $_COOKIE['pll_language'];` in my code?

Comment: Hmm. I tried to replace `$lang = pll_current_language();` with `$lang = $_COOKIE['pll_language'];` and it's working with a bit of delay when clicking the language switcher, so that the page reloads. However, when adding something to the cart and the cart amount updates with AJAX, the cart is set in the 'sv' language (the first language) again. When I reload the page after this, it changes to the correct language.