# How to update quantity in a WooCommerce mini cart via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m working on a project in which my goal is to replace the /cart page of a WooCommerce WordPress site with the “Mini Cart” feature included in WooCommerce.

I’ve updated the Mini Cart to show the addition of products and to allow for removing products, as well as adding and removing coupons all via AJAX.

The last 2 items on my list are to update quantities via AJAX when the included "Update Cart" button is clicked, as well as to show "notices" when items are removed, coupons are added or removed, or an invalid coupon is attempted.

At this point, though, I cannot figure out how to do either effectively.

For reference, here's the bit of code I have for removing an item from the Mini Cart. To be honest, I'm not sure if this is the most efficient, but it seems to be working. However, it doesn't display any notice about an item being removed (whereas on the standard /cart page, it does, though I know it's not using this same code for that).

```
(function ($) {
jQuery(document).on('click', '#slide-out-mini-cart .slide-out-remove', function (e) {

var $thisbutton = $(this),
  $form = $thisbutton.closest('form.woocommerce-cart-form'),
  product_id = $thisbutton.data( "product_id" ),
  cart_item_key = $thisbutton.data("cart_item_key");

if (product_id) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var data = {
    'product_id': product_id,
    'cart_item_key': cart_item_key
  };

  jQuery(document.body).trigger('remove_from_cart', [$thisbutton, data]);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'remove_from_cart'),
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function (response) {
      $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
    },
    complete: function (response) {
      $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
    },
    success: function (response) {                  
      if (response.error & response.product_url) {
        window.location = response.product_url;
        return;
      }
      jQuery(document.body).trigger('removed_from_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
    },
  });
  return false;
}       
});
})(jQuery);
```

I realize this is a bit of a broad set of questions, but at this point, I'm wondering:

1. Is this the most efficient way to accomplish these actions?
2. How can I get the "notices" to show up?
3. Is there a similar script I can use to update Mini Cart quantities via AJAX?

Happy to provide more details, but honestly wasn't sure where to start so leaving it here for now. Thanks!

Comment: this is the link to an answer solved my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941502/refresh-update-minicart-with-ajax-in-woocommerce

Comment: Thanks - I do have something very similar to that in my functions.php file and it does help to facilitate adding, removing, etc. But updating quantities in the mini-cart is where things break down. I'm not sure what the AJAX call should be or how to call the correct function from WooCommerce to do this.